# Printer deamon creates hundreds of symlinks

Tags: printing, symlink, cups

Today I stumbled over hundreds of symbolic links in my OS X `/tmp` folder.

```
> …
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root      wheel    66B 10 Mai 11:42 554f27eaca409 -> /private/etc/cups/ppd/Photosmart_C309a_series_blu___iMac_Buero.ppd
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root      wheel    66B 10 Mai 11:42 554f27ed23fcd -> /private/etc/cups/ppd/Photosmart_C309a_series_blu___iMac_Buero.ppd
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root      wheel    66B 10 Mai 11:42 554f27ef71a19 -> /private/etc/cups/ppd/Photosmart_C309a_series_blu___iMac_Buero.ppd
…
```

I can delete them, but after minutes the folder is stuffed with those links.

Only when I remove all printers, the symlinks will not be created.
Is it normal? How can I prevent it?